# How to compare two ajax responses after parsing

Tags: javascript, ajax

I had write ajax calls for two pages in single function is there any alternate Way to write code for that and also I want to compare those two ajax responses i.e., compare both y2 and y3 objects.

```
function compareResponses() {
    alert('comp');

    // Getting object of ORIGINAL data
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            y = xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert(y);
            y2 = JSON.parse(y);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "2.ashx", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();

    // Getting object of another data
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp1 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp1.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp1.status == 200) {
            y1 = xmlhttp1.responseText;
            //alert(y1);
            y3 = JSON.parse(y1);
        }
        xmlhttp1.open("POST", "1.ashx", true);
        xmlhttp1.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp1.send();
    }
```

Comment: do you want to check whether they are equal or not?

Comment: You're missing a closing brace for the function.

Comment: If you want to send both AJAX requests concurrently, I think you'll need to use promises to wait for both of them to finish. Instead, you can send them consecutively. Have the callback function of the first request make the second request, and the second callback can compare the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use promises for this, because you don't know when (or even IF) both ajax calls will complete.

example implementation (adapt to your scenario):

```
// Promise to be filled with future value
var futureValue = new Promise();

// .then() will return a new promise
var anotherFutureValue = futureValue.then();

// Promise state handlers ( must be a function ).
// The returned value of the fulfilled / failed handler will be the value of the promise.
futureValue.then({

    // Called if/when the promise is fulfilled
    fulfilledHandler: function() {},

    // Called if/when the promise fails
    errorHandler: function() {},

    // Called for progress events (not all implementations of promises have this)
    progressHandler: function() {}
});
```

More info: http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt1-theory-and-semantics

edit: another link from another blog which has the same problem as you:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/